# Estratégia para descobrir se sua aplicação web está sendo parcial ou totalmente censurada por um ISP

Tags: lado-do-servidor, arquitetura-de-software, cliente-servidor

### Pergunta

Como, **conceitualmente falando**,é possível detectar que uma aplicação web foi parcial ou totalmente bloqueada por um provedor de internet?

Duas situações que acredito que poderiam permitir isso seria 1) algum javascript adicional que, por amostragem, retorna falhas em carregar ou realizar funções específicas, associadas ou não a termos e 2) desenvolver uma extensão para navegador que usa IPs desconhecidos e informam quando seu site *fica offline para o usuário*.

### Estudo de caso

O Twitter recentemente confirmou que envio de fotos de pessoas de um dado ISP (provedor de acesso à internet) da Venezuela, controlado pelo governo, está bloqueando envio e exibição de imagens. Provavelmente ocorre apenas *timeout*. Demais operações básicas funcionam.

Outro ponto é que, sysadmins em certas situações conseguem bloquear acesso a requisições que tenham certos termos. Por exemplo, enviar uma requisição não criptografada tentando postar uma mensagem com termos em uma lista negra poderia retornar um erro, sem nem mesmo o provedor de serviço saber.

Nota: outras sugestões de estudo de caso são bem vindas

Comment: O uso de uma VPN resolve todo esse problema.

Comment: Po, algumas regiões do Brasil tem ISP que são confusos.. você não sabe se estão bloqueando ou se está rolando uma operação de man-in-the-middle.. esbarrei num problema onde sacaneavam as requisições.. acho que foi por incompetência mas na dúvida, mudando para https resolveu o dilema!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do ponto de vista do servidor uma comunicação censurada é indistinguível de uma comunicação que nunca foi iniciada pelo cliente. Da mesma forma, do ponto de vista do cliente um site censurado é indistinguível de um site que não existe/está fora do ar. A solução em ambos os casos é buscar um **canal alternativo** na qual a comunicação seja bem sucedida, e usar esse canal para informar sobre a indisponibilidade da comunicação original. Na ausência de tal canal, pode-se no máximo **inferir** que determinado segmento dos seus usuários/visitantes está com algum problema, monitorando por mudanças abruptas no seu padrão de acesso.

> **Nota:** a maneira mais garantida de se evitar uma censura parcial seria usar HTTPS - pois dessa forma todo o conteúdo da comunicação, incluindo [query strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), seria confidencial entre o cliente e o servidor. Entretanto há casos em que isso não é possível (ex.: China, que baniu o uso de HTTPS até onde eu saiba) ou que isso pode ser contornado (ex.: um ataque [**MitM Institucional**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/27820/6939), onde o agente que realiza a censura tem poder sobre o código cliente ou seus [CAs](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoridade_de_Certifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o)).
>
> Em princípio isso poderia ocorrer até aqui no Brasil, mas a [AC-Raiz da ICP-Brasil](http://www.iti.gov.br/certificacao-digital/autoridades-certificadoras) **não é** reconhecida pelos browsers por padrão (motivo pelo qual todo mundo vê alertas de segurança ao acessar sites seguros do governo). Por outro lado, programas que fazem MitM institucional por padrão - como o Opera Mini e o "acelerador" da Nokia - permitem que isso seja feito sem "dar na vista"...

### Canais Alternativos

No caso de uma aplicação parcialmente censurada, uma maneira seria ter um código de erro que identificasse a falha na comunicação, mas construído de forma que esse código fosse comunicado sem problemas. Ou seja, ao enviar `http://example.com/foo?texto=palavra-censurada` e receber um timeout (ou outro erro), o código cliente deveria imediatamente enviar uma segunda requisição a `http://example.com/bar?cod=251` onde o código `251` seria o equivalente a "requisição `foo` falhou". A partir daí, o servidor poderia usar técnicas de mineração de dados/*clustering* ou similares para tentar identificar o que os clientes que falharam têm em comum.

No caso de uma aplicação totalmente bloqueada, a única solução (para os clientes) é tentar usar um proxy (por exemplo, ["down for everyone or just for me?"](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/)). Isso vai lhes permitir saber se o servidor está fora do ar ou se é só eles que não conseguem acessá-los. Se o próprio servidor conseguir manter um proxy desses desbloqueado, então seria viável manter uma extensão no navegador que faz um *ping* a esse proxy sempre que uma tentativa de acessar o site principal falhar (embora a simples existência dessa extensão chamaria a atenção de quem censurou o site, para que censurasse também a extensão...).

#### Peer-to-peer

Na impossibilidade de designar um único servidor para agir como canal alternativo (por esse servidor viver sendo bloqueado, por exemplo) uma possibilidade seria tentar usar comunicações [*peer-to-peer*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer) (P2P) de modo que os usuários trocassem informações entre si acerca do estado do servidor. No browser, o padrão [proposto] [WebRTC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC) pode ser de grande ajuda, quando amplamente suportado (atualmente [já o é no Firefox, Chrome e Opera](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rtcpeerconnection)).

Entretanto, o WebRTC sozinho não resolve o problema do [*NAT Traversal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) - a capacidade de computadores pertencentes a sub-redes diferentes comunicarem uns com os outros. Esse problema *pode* se tornar inexistente com a adoção do [IPv6](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6), no qual há endereços suficientes para todo dispositivo imaginável sem a necessidade de sub-redes (ou melhor dizendo, há a *possibilidade* deles terem um IP global *ainda que* façam parte de uma sub-rede), mas enquanto boa parte dos sistemas ainda usarem IPv4 o NAT Traversal ainda é necessário.

O projeto [**serverless webrtc**](http://blog.printf.net/articles/2013/05/17/webrtc-without-a-signaling-server/) (WebRTC sem um servidor [de sinalização]), por exemplo, elimina a necessidade de qualquer servidor exceto pelo [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) (e existem diversos [servidores](http://code.google.com/p/natvpn/source/browse/trunk/stun_server_list) [públicos](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/STUN) para esse fim) - desde que os pares a se conectar colaborem em um protocolo próprio. Não estudei esse protocolo a fundo, mas creio que seria possível o sistema oferecer facilidades para que isso seja feito *a posteriori* (i.e. negocia-se a conexão proativamente, usa-se a conexão caso a censura ocorra).

### Padrões de Acesso Incomuns

Em geral, como na arquitetura web são os clientes que sempre iniciam uma comunicação, não há como saber com certeza se um bloqueio assim ocorreu. Entretanto, se seu serviço possui um número razoável de visitantes/usuários registrados, pode-se aplicar técnicas de [mineração de dados](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados)/*clustering* para auxiliar na detecção de anomalias.

Digamos que vários clientes pré-existentes pararam de usar o site simultaneamente, a partir da mesma data [aproximadamente]. Em um agrupamento, essa seria uma característica (dimensão? métrica? desculpe, mas só tenho um conhecimento superficial de DM) interessante que reuniria um conjunto de usuários. Se você possui informações sobre a localização geográfica desses usuários (ou outro tipo de informação, como endereços IP) - informações estas que também agrupam usuários em clusters - então o sistema poderá fazer a **correlação** entre uma característica e outra (i.e. local e data de último acesso).

Essa correlação indicaria um problema: seja uma censura, como na discussão presente, seja a queda de um link, como no caso do *network split* (ver [resposta do @Alexandre Marcondes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6712/215)). Medidas auxiliares poderiam então ser tomadas para confirmar ou refutar que uma censura está de fato em progresso.

### Conteúdo Censurado

Por fim, uma breve nota sobre o caso em que certos conteúdos (digamos, palavras-chave) estão sendo censurados, mas o restante da aplicação está ok. É muito difícil o cliente comunicar ao servidor **o que** está sendo censurado, uma vez que a tentativa de "burlar" a censura (via canal alternativo, codificação alternativa, etc) poderia ela própria também ser censurada. Um recurso bastante usado em situações onde a criptografia está indisponível é a [**esteganografia**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esteganografia): uma técnica de [segurança por obscurantismo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seguran%C3%A7a_por_obscurantismo) (*security through obscurity*) que consiste em enviar-se mensagens aparentemente inócuas porém contendo uma segunda mensagem "escondida" na mesma.

Existem ferramentas que possibilitam a esteganografia num grau aceitável de confidencialidade (exigindo uma senha para acessar a parte secreta) e [negação plausível](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nega%C3%A7%C3%A3o_plaus%C3%ADvel) (as variações na mensagem original que escondem o segredo são indistinguíveis de variações aleatórias, resistentes às técnicas mais comuns de análise estatística). Entretanto, a **distribuição** dessas ferramentas tem que se dar em caráter privado (senão o agente da censura também terá acesso às mesmas) - o que torna impraticável empregá-las no contexto de aplicações web. Além disso, a "performance" das mesmas é bem aquém do desejado, já que a mensagem "visível" tem de ser ordens de grandeza maior que a mensagem "invisível".

Comment: Boa resposta. Fico aqui pensando um meio do que você citou como "canal alternativo" não ser um IP fixo mas sim algo variável. Talvez até mesmo pensando em algum conceito de P2P (usar IPs das pessoas que acessam o próprio site). E só ativar esse recurso quando houver desconfiança. Como censuras são pontuais, é mais complicado para um sysadmin sequer saber que a censura estaria bloqueada.

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz Nesse ponto (P2P) o [WebRTC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC) pode ajudar bastante. E quanto a detectar censura, talvez um site bem grande que use uma mineração de dados agressiva nos usuários inativos consiga algum resultado, mas no geral concordo que é uma situação bem problemática...

Comment: Cara, se não quiser fazer agora, pelo menos se nos próximos dias ninguém citar WebRTC, incrementa sua resposta pelo menos citando isso. Essa pergunta vai ficar bem popular esse ano

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz Fiz uma pesquisa rápida sobre WebRTC, e prefiro esperar até o fim de semana (quando estiver menos ocupado), aí eu posso dar uma resposta mais adequada. Infelizmente, enquanto usarmos ipv4 pelo menos, não dá pra evitar a necessidade de um servidor, mesmo para P2P (para [NAT Traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal)). Depois atualizo a resposta com mais detalhes, por ora deixo [esse link](http://blog.printf.net/articles/2013/05/17/webrtc-without-a-signaling-server/) pra quem quiser saber mais.

Answer (score 9):

Para fins de avaliação, vamos assumir que sua aplicação web está configurada de maneira convencional:

- `HTTP` via porta TCP 80
- `HTTPS` via porta TCP 443

E que, por bloqueio, você quer dizer que:

- A conexão nunca chega a ser estabelecida com o servidor, ou
- A conexão recebe uma resposta HTTP indicando falha (501, 404, etc.)

(Isso exclui *impersonation* e *middle-man*, onde ao invés de um bloqueio o agente malicioso implementa un servidor e redireciona as queries DNS de um serviço conhecido para este, e que responde como se fosse o serviço original).

E que a configuração do ambiente segue o seguinte padrão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde, por Internet, quero dizer um conjunto de roteamento que está fora do escopo de controle do ISP.

Temos então duas perguntas:

1. Como determinar um ambiente implementado com o objetivo de causar falhas de requisição?
2. Como contornar as limitações implementadas?

Para início de conversa, é interessante deixar claro que você nunca vai saber deterministicamente (com 100% de certeza) que está sendo bloqueado ativamente. Erros podem ser causados por vários fatores - um DNS mal-configurado, um proxy reinicializado, um cache que está sofrendo *flush*.

Isso dito, podemos separar os bloqueios por escopo.

Seu bloqueio pode ser total, como foi no caso do Egito em 2011. Não só DNS queries falhavam, mas também tentativas de estabelecimento de conexão com serviços públicos como `google.com` e `wikipedia.org`. Com uma tabela de serviços públicos e um script que execute comandos GET nestes serviços é fácil definir se este é o seu caso.

Bloqueios a um site podem ser de dois tipos: Total, onde qualquer chamada ao domínio mencionado recebe um status de falha; ou seletivo, onde um padrão é estabelecido - portas TCP específicas, partes da requisição HTTP (para evitar acesso a uma ou mais páginas ou bloquear um MIME Type específico).

Vamos assumir que é este o caso, e que podemos representar nosso ambiente assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Detecção

A mais básica seria um *protocolo* estabelecido entre o aspectos cliente e servidor da aplicação. Após um `POST` o cliente pode perguntar ao servidor, em uma segunda chamada, se o conteúdo enviado foi recebido com sucesso. Uma resposta negativa pode disparar um aviso de bloqueio.

A segunda é o estabelecimento de servidores secundários (que podem estar geograficamente em uma região diferente do serviço primário) cuja responsabilidade seja apenas de perguntar se, *do ponto de vista deles*, o serviço primário está no ar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se após uma falha no envio de um arquivo a aplicação recebe uma resposta positiva dos servidores secundários, esta pode ser uma indicação que a aplicação está sendo ativamente bloqueada.

### Soluções

No caso de um bloqueio total não há, obviamente, muito a ser feito.

No caso de um bloqueio parcial, o conteúdo a ser enviado pode ser obfuscado, de maneira a impedir a detecção pelo filtro estabelecido. Algumas possibilidades:

- Envio do conteúdo via HTTPS, aproveitando a encriptação nativa do canal, se ainda ativo:
- Envio do conteúdo para uma URL diferente da original;
- Mudança do MIME Type (por exemplo, codificando o arquivo em Base64 e enviando como valor de um campo de texto ao invés de MultiPart)
- Envio segmentado do conteúdo durante várias requisições;
- Envio para um servidor secundário, que irá fazer o redirecionamento do conteúdo para o serviço primário; e
- Tunelamento IP, entre outros.

Várias dessas implementações podem ser combinadas, de maneira a impedir a detecção direta.

Comment: Dei os +50 de gratificação pra você e vou dar outra gratificação para o que está com mais votos do pessoal.   Sua resposta também foi exemplar.

Comment: Obrigado, e concordo; a parte sobre peer-to-peer cobre uma estratégia muito interessante.

Comment: Cara, essa visão foi irada! Me ajudou a resolver um problema sério numa região do brasil onde meu app roda! valeu!

Comment: @EduardoXavier fico feliz em ler isso - e é sempre um prazer ajudar!

Comment: @OnoSendai o provedor de internet da cidadezinha estava corrompendo a transmissão. Talvez mudando o conteúdo e estava ferrando os métodos PUT, DELETE... só POST e GET funcionavam.. mudei para o protocolo https e app passou a rodar tranquilo! Como explica isso para o cliente? Não explica!!! Mas te agradeço muito!

Answer (score 6):

Como se valida hoje a "confiabilidade" de arquivos?

Usando **[MD5](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)** e gerando um [hash](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash) code.

Uma maneira interessante de validar se houve modificação de conteúdo entre o servidor e o cliente seria gerar um hash a partir do que será entregue. Enviá-lo para o cliente e um script (javascript) faria a validação do conteúdo. 
Mesma coisa a comunicação Cliente - Servidor, o cliente geraria um hash e enviaria em uma comunicação diferente (talvez por [Ajax](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX_%28programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29)) para o servidor antes de postar os dados de um formulário por exemplo.

Como base para estudo usaria o [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/);

Porém, se o acesso ao servidor for **totalmente** bloqueado, este não vai ter como saber que o cliente está tentando contato, nesse caso seria necessário o uso de uma alternativa de tunelamento como exemplo o uso de [proxy](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy) ou da rede [tor](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28rede_de_anonimato%29).

> @mgibsonbr Sugeriu como fonte de estudo também:
>   [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha-2) - Script para gerar o hash
>   [Stanford Javascript Crypto Library](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/) - Biblioteca de cript pra javascript

Comment: Se o script vem do servidor, e o servidor está sendo censurado, como confiar no script? Isso até pode funcionar se você usar dois servidores (e no caso, eu usaria SHA-2 em vez de MD5 e [sjcl](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/) em vez de crypto-js), ou um plugin/extensão no navegador com esse código, mas com um site só é impossível. Em particular se quem estiver censurando for o governo ou outra entidade em posição de executar um **MitM Institucional** (i.e. com a colaboração de um CA).

Comment: Então, se a questão for bloqueios seletivos, e a aplicação tiver como base para "funcionar" um script que validaria o que foi enviado ao cliente (pelo próprio cliente), não seria impossível bloquear esse script, mas o ISP teria que "injetar" um outro script para substituir essa necessidade, caso contrário a aplicação cliente rejeitaria por não conseguir "validar". Realmente daria trabalho construir essa "aplicação" no cliente. Concordo sobre o algoritmo, sobre a biblioteca eu não conheço, mas será um bom estudo. :)

Comment: Está certo, a pergunta foi sobre censura, não MitM, então a princípio pode-se assumir como premissa que os scripts baixados do servidor continuarão intactos. Mas ainda não entendo como um hash (ou mesmo um HMAC) poderia ajudar a diferenciar entre, digamos, um timeout e uma censura... Poderia dar um exemplo? (a propósito, eu sugeri o SHA-2 porque ele é mais indicado em situações onde a segurança está envolvida, mas se a preocupação for apenas **integridade** então o MD5 pode ser sim uma boa solução - em especial pela sua performance superior)

Comment: Se você está recebendo erro do servidor fica fácil detectar que há um problema, que pode ser por vários motivos, a questão seria quando não há erro, o conteúdo chega, mas chega modificado pode-se dizer que houve um MitM (com alteração de conteúdo), dessa maneira um hash ajudaria a validar a informação, mas o hash tb pode sofrer MitM, então esse hash teria que ser validado de alguma forma. Um exemplo seria usar par de chaves (no caso do cliente publica enviado ao servidor, e privada, gerado localmente pela aplicação javascript no bowser), e o contrário HTTPS seria uma solução...

Comment: Exato, em caso de problemas dessa tipo, eu recomendo o uso de uma VPN. Paga de preferencia, a propósito proxy.sh é uma excelente opção. Mas tambem existem opções gratuitas como -> http://198-200-84-181.cpe.distributel.net:61929/en/about.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Infelizmente este tipo de coisa (censura e bloqueios por meio de Firewalls e Proxies) não tem como serem detectados ativamente pelo servidor. Os clientes que antes conectavam não vão conseguir mais ter acesso e o servidor fica isolado. Como é o caso que acontece num `network split`, por exemplo onde cada segmento da rede fica isolado entre si. No caso do `network split` pode ser algo não intencional, mas o efeito é o mesmo. Por exemplo:

> Partiu um cabo de fibra ótica que leva a Internet do Brasil para a Europa e outro >dos EUA para a Europa. Neste caso as Américas não vão conseguir se comunicar com a Europa, mas a Internet continua funcionado para os dois em outros casos.

A melhor solução para isso é ter vários servidores nos locais em que se quer monitorar e testar o acesso ao seu site ativamente de dentro da rede alvo. Por exemplo:

- Ter servidores em todos os continentes ou países alvo de teste para saber se de dentro do país X você consegue acessar seu site.
- Ter servidores usando a as conexões de todos os ISPs que você quer testar para saber se um ISP específico bloqueou seu site
- Ter agentes distribuídos (programinhas que as pessoas instalam para monitorar seu site)
- Ter plugins de browser que atuem como agentes verificando o acesso ao seu site

Nenhum tipo de validação, Hash ou critpografia vai ajudar na detecção de censura ou bloqueio, mas eles podem ajudar na detecção de alterações, manipulações ou adulterações no conteúdo distribuído pelo site.

Answer (score 0):

***Visão de infra:***

Apenas no caso de conteúdo *parcialmente bloqueado*, poderia contabilizar as visualizações de navegadores válidos e cruzar com a referencia de acesso dos demais dados.

**por exemplo:** uma imagem só é chamada quando a home é visualizada, caso a contagem de visualizações dessa imagem seja muito menor que a da pagina "mãe" é possível que o conteúdo esteja sendo parcialmente bloqueado, com conteúdo em texto pode-se fazer chamadas em js que carreguem o texto e incrementem o esqueleto enviado como "mãe"

porem existem problemas nessa abordagem, cache de todos os tipos que devem ser evitado com headers como *cache-control* (onerando obviamente mais banda e processamento), alem de caso opte por texto dinâmico client side, vai perder quase toda relevância ao google...