# Ataques de interceptação de dados

Tags: segurança, http

Quais os ataques de interceptação de dados conhecidos, tipo *Man-in-the-middle*?

Comment: O problema não são os conhecidos e sim os desconhecidos :)

Comment: Você quer algo como uma lista de técnicas para realizar MitM? Se algo desse tipo existe, vai estar por exemplo na [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack). Ou você procura outra coisa? [Essa pergunta relacionada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7051/215) por exemplo trata da descrição conceitual do ataque, mas não entra em detalhes quanto às principais técnicas. Se você der uma melhorada na pergunta - especificando exatamente o que espera de uma resposta - talvez dê para respondê-la sem que ela fique ampla demais.

Comment: @bigown primeiro cuidamos dos parentes depois dos que não conhecemos

Comment: eu conheço o http://www.aircrack-ng.org/ já usei quando estava sem internet, dai eu ficava na varanda do meu apto. só snifando wifi dos outros até conseguir a senha ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Macro-categorias

Os ataques de interceptação podem ser classificados em três grandes grupos - *eavesdropping*, *Man-in-the-Middle* e *Denial of Service* - dependendo do que o atacante faz (ou é capaz de fazer) com os dados interceptados - somente ler, ler e modificar, ou simplesmente jogá-los fora (não repassar ao destino).

### *Eavesdropping*

Alice está se comunicando com Bob, e a comunicação passa por Eve. Eve observa toda a comunicação, contudo sem alterá-la de nenhuma forma. Em outras palavras, Eve apenas tem acesso de **leitura** à comunicação.

- Causas: se o conteúdo da comunicação for assinado (garantindo sua integridade e autenticidade), mas não cifrado (o que garantiria sua confidencialidade), abre-se as portas para esse ataque. No caso, o atacante precisaria estar ou no meio da comunicação (i.e. controlar um dos nós entre Alice e Bob) ou meramente ser um dos participantes da mesma (ex.: estar na mesma rede que ambos, por exemplo uma rede sem fio).
- Consequências: vazamento de informações sigilosas.
- Como prevenir: encriptando o canal de comunicações. O uso de TLS/SSL não só garante a confidencialidade como também autentica *pelo menos um dos lados* - desde que o mesmo use um certificado de segurança válido ao realizar o aperto-de-mão (se o cliente não autenticar corretamente o servidor, ainda é possível Eve convencer tanto Alice quanto Bob a se comunicarem com ela, não um com o outro).

### *Man-in-the-Middle*

Alice está se comunicando com Bob, e a comunicação passa por Mallory. Mallory não só observa toda a comunicação como pode deixar de entregar mensagens, mandar suas próprias mensagens e/ou substituir uma mensagem do remetente original por outra de sua autoria.

- Causas:

  - Alice e Bob não se autenticaram mutuamente de forma correta; Mallory **personificou** (*impersonated*) Bob para Alice e vice-versa, de modo que cada um deles pensa que está se comunicando com seu par, quando na realidade estão ambos comunicando com Mallory. Isso pode ocorrer mesmo se o canal de comunicações estiver protegido.
  - A comunicação é cifrada mas não é autenticada/assinada; um erro comum, ao menos na sua concepção - que basta encriptar os dados para eles estarem seguros. Na realidade, se Alice enviou várias mensagens pra Bob, e Mallory guardou essas mensagens, pode ocorrer de no futuro uma nova mensagem ser substituída por uma das antigas (que Mallory presumiu/deduziu ser interessante pros seus propósitos).
- Consequências: os dados trocados não são confiáveis, e são potencialmente danosos, já que foram manipulados por um adversário.
- Como prevenir: utilizando um protocolo que assegure autenticidade, integridade e confidencialidade, como o TLS/SSL, **e** sendo cuidadoso ao realizar a autenticação mútua (o cliente tem que verificar se o certificado do servidor é válido, e o servidor precisa conferir as credenciais do cliente - usuário/senha, certificado, chave...).

#### MitM Institucional

Variante do MitM, porém executado por uma das **âncoras de confiança** (*trust anchors*) do sistema. A título de exemplo, se uma Autoridade Certificadora (CA) criar pra si própria um certificado inválido (ex.: associando o nome `facebook.com` ao seu próprio par de chaves), ou se o fabricante/distribuidor de um *browser* instalar no mesmo um Certificado Raiz (*root certificate*) de uma CA fraudulenta, estes poderiam executar um MitM nos moldes do primeiro item acima, em "causas".

- Causas: corrupção; abuso da confiança dos clientes (ex.: Opera Mini, que [implementa MitM institucional por padrão](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/redirection-and-decryption-of-mobile-traffic-is-your-browser-a-mitm/) como parte do seu "acelerador da web"; o ["Navegador" da Velox](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/brasil/fc3103201005.htm) - não confundir com *browser*, o nome foi escolhido com o intuito premeditado de causar confusão).
- Consequências: poder ilegítimo de vigilância (*surveillance*) a um agente que não possui (ou não deveria possuir) acesso *de jure* ao conteúdo privado dos usuários.
- Como prevenir: nenhum meio viável em larga escala; em casos pontuais, pode-se abandonar a Infraestrutura de Chave Pública (PKI) em prol da *Web of Trust* (ex.: utilizando PGP, e trocando certificados pessoalmente com seus pares). Um meio de mitigar (mas não eliminar) esse risco no *browser* é através do uso de ferramentas como o [Convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_%28SSL%29) - que acrescenta certa **redundância** no processo de estabelecimento de confiança, tornando mais difícil que um único agente isolado execute esse ataque sem conspirar com a maioria dos outros.

### *Denial of Service* (DoS)

Diferente das demais categorias, um DoS não "intercepta" dados no sentido de lê-los ou alterá-los, entretanto optei por incluí-lo aqui pois pode ser usado como instrumento de censura (i.e. o atacante não sabe o que está sendo comunicado nem interfere no conteúdo da comunicação, apenas impede que a comunicação seja concluída de fato). Para mais detalhes sobre esse cenário, ver [essa pergunta relacionada ao assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6127/215).

## Principais técnicas

A forma mais comum de interceptação ocorre na rede local em que um computador/dispositivo está, através de técnicas como [*ARP Poisoning*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing), *802.11q Retracing*, *STP-Trunk Hijacking*, *RIPv1 routing information injection* (Nota: só as conheço de nome, não saberia explicar o que fazem). Isso pode ser feito por qualquer um que pertença à rede, de modo que a menos que se esteja numa rede "segura" (i.e. onde se conhece todos os participantes, e estes são confiáveis) se está vulnerável a esse tipo de ataque. É também um bom argumento em favor de proteger sua rede Wi-Fi adequadamente, não deixá-la aberta mesmo que tenha recursos para compartilhá-la com quem bem entender.

Mas uma rede local não é o único lugar que um MitM pode ocorrer: a Internet é composta de milhares de *endpoints* conhecidos como ASes (Sistemas Autônomos), e eles roteiam os dados segundo um protocolo chamado BGP (*Border Gateway Protocol*). Como o BGP confia nas rotas fornecidas pelos outros ASes, com suficiente manipulação de um deles qualquer rota pode levar a qualquer AS. E como mudanças nas rotas não são incomuns, é difícil distinguir entre uma ocorrência normal e um ataque em andamento. A consequência disso é que não basta você confiar no seu ISP, ou no servidor de hospedagem onde está seu servidor, etc, no meio do caminho entre um e outro pode estar um atacante.

Há também os ataques que envolvem o DNS. Semlhante ao *ARP spoofing* há o [*DNS spoofing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_spoofing), em que dados incorretos são introduzidos na cache dos sistemas de DNS de modo que os nomes sejam resolvidos para um endereço IP diferente (controlado pelo atacante). Outros ataques que permitam obter controle de um sistema DNS também podem ser usados para direcionar tráfego ao sistema do atacante.

<sub>[Fonte](https://serverfault.com/a/153065/106111). [Outra referência interessante](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/33911/6939).</sub>

## Ataques que *habilitam* a interceptação de dados

Além dos ataques especificamente voltados à interceptação, há aqueles que possuem outros objetivos - mais amplos - mas que acabam também por incluir a *possibilidade* de interceptação. Citarei apenas dois, pois servem para ilustrar como fatores externos ao processo de assegurar a comunicação podem acabar por comprometê-la apesar dos cuidados:

#### Injeção

Os ataques de injeção (*injection*) - não só SQL Injection, Shell Injection, etc, mas também *Cross-Site Scripting* (XSS) - podem ser utilizados para realizar a interceptação de dados. No caso eles agem **antes** do protocolo seguro de comunicação iniciar (quando os dados ainda estão no seu formato plano no lado remetente) ou **depois** desse protocolo terminar (quando os dados já foram convertidos de volta para seu formato plano no lado destinatário).

#### *Confused Deputy*

Trata-se confundir um dos agentes responsáveis pela segurança do sistema a executar ações aparentemente legítimas, porém orquestradas pelo atacante de modo a lhe beneficiar. Frequentemente, o agente em questão é **o próprio usuário!** O [*Clickjacking*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) é o exemplo "canônico", mas para um exemplo mais voltado à interceptação, pense na situação em que o usuário acha que está utilizando o site X quando na realidade ele está no site Y. Isso pode decorrer da simples falta de atenção (não verificar a barra de endereços, principalmente o "cadeado"), de limitações na midia utilizada (um aplicativo em tela cheia que "simula" um browser visitando um outro endereço), até ataques mais sofisticados como [esse aqui](http://lcamtuf.blogspot.com.br/2011/12/old-switcharoo.html) - em que um site é trocado por outro de forma quase imperceptível, levando o usuário a interagir com o site do atacante achando que ainda está no site legítimo.

Citei esses exemplos apenas pra salientar que - por mais que se dê atenção à proteção dos dados e da comunicação - nada disso vale se o *sistema* (hardware, software) não for confiável e/ou se os usuários não estiverem *cientes* da necessidade e da importância de fazer a sua parte. São ataques que - de forma similar aos [*side-channel attacks*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack) da criptografia - não tentam atuar "dentro do sistema" (i.e. assumindo-se que os protocolos de segurança foram executados em sucesso, e agindo nesse contexto) mas sim "subverter o sistema de fora pra dentro" (impedindo os protocolos de cumprir o seu papel na segurança).

Answer (score 9):

Na área de criptografia e segurança informática, o conceito de MITM (Man in the middle), permite que numa comunicação entre dois sujeitos (Sujeito A e Sujeito B), exista secretamente um terceiro sujeito (Sujeito C), que efectua o *relay* das comunicações entre o A e o B, de forma bi-direccional.

De forma a explicar melhor este conceito, apresento uma imagem ilustrativa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não vou apresentar métododos de ataque, nem como podem ser realizados, porém poderemos fácilmente afirmar que o MITM, é fortemente utilizado por várias agências de segurança, em todo o mundo

Apresento porém alguns dos métodos de defesa contra ataques MITM, que podem e devem ser implementados pelos SysAdmin:

- DNSSEC: Secure DNS Extensions;
- PKI: Public Keys Infrastructures;
- DKIM: DomainKeys Identified Mail;
- SSL pinning;
- Quantum cryptography;

A defesa destes ataques não é algo de fácil implementação, visto que envolve não só conhecimentos técnicos, mas mais importante a camada de utilizadores aos quais é sempre muito dificil explicar cenários de *exploit* criptográfico e *routing* de dados entre um ou mais pontos, numa rede.

Além do conceito MITM, existem outros conceitos idênticos, com abordagens idênticas, porém com intervenientes distintos.
Falo do conceito MITB (Man in the browser). Um dos BOTS mais célebres com que se tem desenvolvido estes ataques é o *Trojan Spy:W32/ZBOT*.

**Referências:**

- http://www.kurzweilai.net/a-multi-photon-approach-to-quantum-cryptography
- http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.4797
- http://blog.codinghorror.com/captcha-effectiveness/
- http://petmail.lothar.com/design.html#auto35
- http://ro.ecu.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1014&context=ism
- https://www.f-secure.com/v-descs/trojan-spy_w32_zbot.shtml