# Como proteger minha aplicação JSON?

Tags: php, json, api

Criei um subdomínio exclusivo para fornecer dados das minhas tabelas em JSON, o mesmo facilita requisições tanto para a versão mobile quanto para a versão desktop do meu site, porém eu gostaria de proteger tais dados ou pelo ao menos dificultar o acesso aos mesmo, o que eu poderia fazer?

Já pensei em gerar um token de acesso pra validar a requisição no servidor, mas isso invalidaria o cache da página (algo que quero manter), não da pra usar sessions pois estão em domínios diferentes, seria possível pelo ao menos bloquear o acesso direto pela URL?

Também estou testando o método abaixo, mas não estou certo de que é seguro

```
$origem = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];

if ($origem == "http://www.dominio.com" || $origem == "http://m.dominio.com")
{  
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $origem");
}
```

Não acredito que dessa forma seja segura pois os dados ainda são acessíveis através da url direta da api, mesmo que o individuo possa não conseguir fazer requisições ele ainda pode abrir a pagina e copiar os dados gerados.

Comment: Fez algum teste utilizando o header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. ?

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo do que estou usando para tal @Maurivan

Comment: Tens razão, pela URL ficará acessível.
Tente então restringir por `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] ou $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` já que apenas 2 hosts que terão acesso.

Answer (score 3):

**Resumo:** Não há como, não que eu seja pessimista, mas de fato não há como.

---

### Proteção de CSRF:

Se está preocupado de alguém ler o conteúdo, existem duas situações "distintas":

1. Obter o seu `/json.json` no lado do cliente, via Javascript/Ajax.
2. Obter o seu `/json.json` no lado do "servidor"/"cliente", via cURL/Wget/Webviewer (e "navegadores personalizados").

---

A primeira situação é mais fácil e de fato "há o que fazer" para impedir:

1. Adicionar o cabeçalho de `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, estrito para o seu website.

   - (Opcional) Adicione o `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, limite os cabeçalhos (ex. `X-CRSF-TOKEN`) que podem ser enviados.
   - (Opcional) Adicione o `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, limite os métodos aceitos (ex. `GET`) assim somente este método será aceito.

Logo poderá utilizar:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.dominio.com http://m.dominio.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
```

[Recomendo ver esta resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3183/requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-cross-domain-com-javascript-puro-sem-apis/3251#3251)

2. Adicionar um `CSRF Token`.

   - O CSRF Token deve ser válido apenas para uma única sessão.
   - (Recomendado) O *CSRF Token* deve ser válido para um único IP.
   - (Opcional) O *CSRF Token* deve expirá após um único uso.
   - (Opcional) O *CSRF Token* deve único para cada URL ou para cada seguimento.

[Pode ler esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114663/como-prevenir-o-ataque-csrf-sem-frameworks-php/116437#116437), *apensar de descordar e não recomendar o uso do `generateRandomString()` por ser um [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)*.

Medidas pouco eficientes, mas que podem ajudar:

3. Verificar o `Referrer`/`Origin`, *são facilmente falsificados*.

---

A segunda situação é impossível de ser corrigida, literalmente, não há como impedir isso, tudo listado acima não é suficiente para impedir o uso de cURL/Wget.

1. Criar um `Rate-Limit`, um limite de quantas vezes a página pode ser acessada por segundo por IP (ou faixa de IPv6) é relativamente eficiente, pois exigirá o uso de vários proxies caso deseja obter o conteúdo constantemente, *mas lembre-se do CGNAT no IPv4*.
2. Bloquear acesso via TOR e proxies públicos.

Medidas bem menos eficientes, mas que podem ajudar:

3. Criar um "desafio" em Javascript, como por exemplo o `jjencode`, *o CloudFlare utiliza isto*.

---

<sub><sub>Podem haver outros problemas de segurança, que não é o CSRF, como por exemplo o [MiTM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58389/15089), [XSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75479/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-recursos-e-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-externas-para-maior-seguran%C3%A7a/75492#75492), [DoS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58389/15089) *(inclusive o `json_decode`, padrão, é vulnerável por hash-dos)* e entre outros problemas como Side-Channel Attacks, mas isto são outras coisas que não tem relação com a pergunta...</sub></sub>

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar [autenticação de acesso básica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

Sirva o JSON somente sobre HTTPS. Daí você utiliza o cabeçalho `Authorization` para passar credenciais, codificadas com Base64. Segue um exemplo de como ficaria o cabeçalho, tirado diretamente do wiki:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l
```

No servidor você extrai as credenciais do cabeçalho e autentica a requisição. Dessa forma somente usuários autenticados terão acesso ao JSON.

Em tempo, pois sempre surge esse comentário: eu sei que Base64 não confere segurança alguma. A segurança está no protocolo HTTPS. O Base64 serve para seguir o padrão desse tipo de autenticação.