# Como pegar um dado JSON nesse caso

Tags: php, json

Não estou conseguindo pegar um dado JSON nesse caso:

Uso este site apenas para testes próprios

https://devjp.xyz/data.json

Tentei algumas combinações:

```
            $url = "https://devjp.xyz/data.json";
            $json = file_get_contents($url);
            $json_data = json_decode($json, true);


            echo $json_data['results'][0]['bitcoin'][0]['mercadobitcoin']['buy'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com `json_decode` e `file_get_contents` você não irá conseguir pois ele está bloqueado.

**Minha solução:**

Você poderá usar um stream que irá ler o arquivo e transformá-lo em string para que seja utilizado. Veja:

```
// abro uma stream com fopen
$stream = fopen("https://devjp.xyz/data.json", 'r');
$conteudo = stream_get_contents ($stream, -1); // insiro o conteúdo em uma variável
fclose($stream); // fecho o stream

// após pegar o conteúdo eu procuro a palavra 'mercadobitcoin'
// a partir de então o restante do conteúdo será resgatado a partir daquela palavra
$mercadobitcoin = strstr($conteudo, 'mercadobitcoin');

// a mesma coisa acontece aqui
$buy = strstr($mercadobitcoin, 'buy');

// separo para deixar apenas parte que interessa '$val[0]'
$val = explode(",", $buy);

// a mesma coisa, mas agora eu separo a string buy da string 32399.99
$valor = explode(":", $val[0]);

// mostro o valor
echo $valor[1]; // 32399.99
```

Infelizmente você terá um trabalho para criar uma função que padronizará isso.

Espero que te ajude.

Comment: Ajudou sim ahhaha Muito obrigado!! Mas isso é uma gambiarra ou não tem outro método?

Comment: @JoãoPedroMorais é meio que uma gambiarra. Pois o site bloqueou o uso do `json_decode`.

Comment: Então a única forma de usar é tratando o conteúdo como uma string.

Comment: Parâmetros:

format: (formato de resposta)
- json
- json-cors (liberado para AJAX, requer chave com domínio correto)
- php-serialize
- debug (resposta em JSON indentado, recomenda-se apenas para leitura)

Comment: Na api tem isso, significa alguma coisa?

Comment: @JoãoPedroMorais Provavelmente sim. Mas eu não sei o que é. Você precisa ver direito como configura, ai será mais fácil de pegar os valores.

Comment: https://hgbrasil.com/status/finance/ estou pegando desse site

Comment: @JoãoPedroMorais Pelo que eu ví precisa de uma chave para cadastrar lá e coloca-la no seu site (aplicação). Ai provavelmente você terá acesso mais fácil.

Comment: Oque é esse bloqueio de json_decode? é alguma coisa na forma da resposta ou bloqueio pelo servidor?

Comment: @JoãoPedroMorais os dois. O servidor bloqueia e o conteúdo que você pega vem com esse bloqueio.

Comment: @JoãoPedroMorais dá uma olhada. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199199/como-proteger-minha-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-json

Comment: Criei uma key la pra mim, agora como sei que ele ta liberando o json_decode

Comment: Consegui!!! Mas aprendi bastante sobre json com vc vlw msm!     
$json_data['results']['bitcoin']['mercadobitcoin']['buy'];

Comment: era só liberar a key la, eu não sabia que existia essa de bloqueio de json decode

Comment: @JoãoPedroMorais exato. Imaginei que era isso.

Comment: @JoãoPedroMorais tranquilo amigo! Boa sorte! Abraço!